# Half of my monitor has suddenly turned green since yesterday

Tags: windows-10, display

When I'm on Discord, half of my monitor suddenly turns green. I've tried restarting it, but it didn't work.
I have tried all the tricks but none of them work.

[image: This is the tinted green screen]

Comment: Try a different monitor. That will divide the problem in two.

Comment: Almost certainly a physical issue with the monitor, such as damage due to pressure or impact or water infiltration. It *might* clear up with time, if not severe... or not.